# Jupyter kernel restarting

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

My jupyter notebook always crashes restarts after installing anaconda.

Without installing anaconda there is no problem, with pip jupyter notebook. After anaconda 4 installation,

```
No module named ipykernel_launcher
```

Kernel constantly crashes.